# Need help to get browsersuport for gradiens in css3 to work

Tags: css

I cannot get gradients to work with safari. What am I missing here?

Here is my code:

```
@keyFrames changeSizeAndColor{
    from{ width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          background-color: blue;
          font-size: 5px; 
      }
    to{ width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        font-size: 25px; 
    background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(red, yellow 10%, green      20%);
    background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(red, yellow 10%, green 20%);
    background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(red, yellow 10%, green 20%);
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(red, yellow 10%, green 20%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@-webkit-keyframes changeSizeAndColor{}` for Chrome, Safari, Opera

see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/q12bh4se/6/